# Basic shiny app. Why doesn't source('app.R') work?

Tags: r, shiny

Just getting started with shiny and wondering if I am missing a basic concept here? I have a simple(empty) app set up as below.

```
library(shiny)

source('./code/ui.R')
source('./code/server.R')

shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

runApp() works just fine as does selecting the code block and running. However, source('app.R') doesn't launch the shiny app. Why?

Comment: From `?shinyApp`: *"Value: An object that represents the app. Printing the object or passing it to 'runApp()' will run the app."*. Objects created in a sourced file are not by default `print`ed (though they can explicitly print if desired). If you `print(shinyApp(...))`, it may work.

Comment: using with print() works indeed. Thanks!